# Suggestion for a book on graphic trends and their evolution

Tags: trends

I have been researching about graphic design trends and its evolution. Can someone please suggest a particular book or website about this subject?

Answer (score 2):

[Meggs' History of Graphic Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470168730) is the one that we used in college and I go back to it more than any other textbook. It starts with hieroglyphics and cave paintings and goes all the way up to the modern times. It's a great resource for inspiration and knowledge...I can't recommend it enough!

If cost is an issue, [go back an edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003V0STEK) and pick up a used copy.